# Mail: template reply

Tags: mail.app

I have created an e-mail template in Mail OSX and would like to use it as a reply (but **not as an automatic reply**) to some e-mails I receive to speed up work. Is there a way to reply using a template other than just copy-paste? (Is there a "use template answer" command?) The Mailbutler application does something similar but it is for a fee.

Answer (score 1):

Build what you need as a signature.

Even have different signatures for each mail account.